# Delete row from dataframe having "None" value in all the columns - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I need to delete the row completely in a dataframe having "None" value in all the columns. I am using the following code -

```
df.dropna(axis=0,how='all',thresh=None,subset=None,inplace=True)
```

This does not bring any difference to the dataframe. The rows with "None" value are still there.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There `None`s should be strings, so use replace first:

```
df = df.replace('None', np.nan).dropna(how='all')

df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':['None','a', 'None'],
         'b':['None','g', 'None'],
         'c':['None','v', 'b'],
})

print (df)
      a     b     c
0  None  None  None
1     a     g     v
2  None  None     b

df1 = df.replace('None', np.nan).dropna(how='all')
print (df1)
     a    b  c
1    a    g  v
2  NaN  NaN  b
```

Or test values `None` with not equal and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df.ne('None').any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
      a     b  c
1     a     g  v
2  None  None  b
```

Comment: The row is still there.

Comment: If check number of row with this values e. g. 5 row - `print(df.loc[5].unique())` ?

Comment: There are empty rows present in between data.

Comment: @TeeKay - Do you think `['']` ?

Comment: When I print the dataframe it show "None" and the csv that is generated has empty rows.

Comment: Yes, so if use `print(df.loc[5].unique())` get `['None']` ? or `['']` or something else? Here is 5 rows filled by Nones, which cannot be replaced.

Comment: I get ['None'].

Comment: It i weird, because exacly this doing my solution - all rows with only `'None'` are removed :(

Comment: This is working locally. But when I do the same on Google Cloud Functions, it does not work. Also, there is no error, but the file still has empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should be dropping in the axis `1`. Use the `how` keyword to drop columns with `any` or `all` `NaN` values. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[-1, 0, np.nan], 'c':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
df
   a    b    c
0  1 -1.0  NaN
1  2  0.0  NaN
2  3  NaN  5.0

df.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
   a    b
0  1 -1.0
1  2  0.0
2  3  NaN
```

Comment: OP need `I need to delete the row completely in a dataframe having "None" value in all the columns.`

Comment: That's true, I misread it.
Not sure why he needs the `subset` and `thresh` argument. Maybe try to remove them.

Comment: ya, it is default values, should be omited.

Comment: You removed the whole column. I need to remove a row.